# 'badCertificateCallback' for CronetClient and CupertinoClient

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

Previously I was using the regular `http.Client` from the dart `http` package. I had implemented the following to allow any certificate in debug mode:

```dart
class BadCertificateHttpOverrides extends io.HttpOverrides {
  @override
  io.HttpClient createHttpClient(io.SecurityContext? context) {
    bool callback(io.X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;

    return super.createHttpClient(context)..badCertificateCallback = callback;
  }
}
```

```dart
if (kDebugMode) {
  // Override to allow arbitrary certificates in debug mode
  io.HttpOverrides.global = BadCertificateHttpOverrides();
}
```

However, I've now started using the [`CronetClient`](https://pub.dev/packages/cronet_http) and the [`CupertinoClient`](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_http) on Android and iOS respectively, as suggested by the `http` package's documentation, and this no longer works.

Is there a similar way for both these implementations to allow arbitrary certificates in debug mode?